# How can I call the SOAP function such as checkUser(param: ns1:UserAuthParam)

Tags: python, soap, soap-client, zeep

I am new to SOAP API.

I am groping my way for now.

I am trying to call the SOAP function.

I have WSDL file which has this code:

```
   <element name="checkUser">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="param" nillable="true" type="impl:UserAuthParam"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
```

then it has `UserAuthParam` like this,

```
   <complexType name="UserAuthParam">
    <sequence>
     <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
```

I convert this

```
$python -mzeep UserCheck.wsdl > wsdl.txt
```

in `wsdl.txt`

```
Service: UserAuthService
     Port: UserAuth (Soap11Binding: {http://userauth.user.service.okm.com}UserAuthSoapBinding)
         Operations:
             checkUser(param: ns1:UserAuthParam) -> checkExecuteReturn: ns1:UserAuthParamOut
```

I made this coding to test.

```
import zeep
client = zeep.Client(wsdl="UserCheck.wsdl")
res = client.service.checkUser(userId=12,password="kkkxxx")
```

However, this shows error

> TypeError: {http://userauth.user.service.okm.com}checkUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userId'. Signature: `param: {http://userauth.user.service.okm.com}UserAuthParam`

Maybe my calling method is wrong, but How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your operation is declared as `checkUser(param: ns1:UserAuthParam)`. This method signature says you have one parameter of type `ns1:UserAuthParam`.

One parameter, not two. You can't call it like `checkUser(userId=12,password="kkkxxx")`.

If you look into your wsdl.txt file, you will see the `ns1:UserAuthParam` type declared, which will most likely have the two parameters in its constructor because of how the element is declared:

```
   <complexType name="UserAuthParam">
    <sequence>
     <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
```

So you need one object of this type. Your code should be something like:

```
client = zeep.Client(wsdl="UserCheck.wsdl")
user_auth_type = client.get_type("ns1:UserAuthParam")
user_auth = user_auth_type(userId="12", password="kkkxxx")
res = client.service.checkUser(user_auth)
```